# How to assign diffrent popup with same function with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

so I have this program I am trying to type and I found different ways to write the code but the same popup screen comes how do I call the same function but show different headers when clicked? I have tried to use the same function with different classes called but IDK why everything disappears but I haven't coded javascript very much and still new to me. Please help me the way I am trying to am at is when Wedding button is clicked I want to show "you clicked wedding button" when the birthday is clicked "birthday button"..etc, problem is that the wedding functions is only showing how do I fix it?

```js
/*wedding popup to fill */
const modal = document.querySelector(".modal");
const wedding_POPUP = document.querySelector(".wedding_POPUP");
const closeButton = document.querySelector(".close-button");

function toggleModal() {
  modal.classList.toggle("show-modal");
}

function windowOnClick(event) {
  if (event.target === modal) {
    toggleModal();
  }
}

wedding_POPUP.addEventListener("click", toggleModal);
closeButton.addEventListener("click", toggleModal);
window.addEventListener("click", windowOnClick);
```

```css
/* Popup screen for each modal when pressed 
   buttons when pressed background changes
   setup for when clicked*/

.modal {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: scale(1.1);
  transition: visibility 0s linear 0.25s, opacity 0.25s 0s, transform 0.25s;
}


/*center of page  with padding and borders*/

.modal-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 359px;
  left: 624px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: white;
  padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
  width: 34%;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  height: 122%;
}


/*close button layout with hover background*/

.close-button {
  float: right;
  width: 1.5rem;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.close-button:hover {
  background-color: darkgray;
}


/*style of modal when its open */

.show-modal {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scale(1.0);
  transition: visibility 0s linear 0s, opacity 0.25s 0s, transform 0.25s;
}
```

```html
<div id="occasion">
  <button id="occassion_layout" class="wedding_POPUP">Wedding</button>
  <button id="occassion_layout" class="Birthday_POPUP">Birthday</button>
  <button id="occassion_layout" class="Party_POPUP">Holiday</button>
</div>


<div id="Wed_fill">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>

  <!--when the wedding button is pusehed what it will show show div boderline-->
  <div class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <span class="close-button">&times;</span>

      <p>Wedding button clicked</p>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>

<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close-button">&times;</span>

    <!--form for birthday-->
    <div class="Birth_fill">
      <div class="Birthday_form">
        <p>HAPPY BIRTHDAY button clicked</p>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>

<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close-button">&times;</span>

    <!--form for birthday-->
    <div class="party_filled">
      <div class="party_form">
        <p>Party button clicked</p>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid with duplicate id's `id="occassion_layout"` ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id

Answer (score 0):

Add an attribute to the button that relates it to the corresponding modal, so you can toggle that modal.

```js
/*wedding popup to fill */
const modal = document.querySelector(".modal");
const wedding_POPUP = document.querySelector(".wedding_POPUP");
const closeButton = document.querySelector(".close-button");

function closeModal() {
  document.querySelectorAll(".modal").forEach(el => el.classList.remove("show-modal"));
}

function toggleModal(e) {
  let modal = document.getElementById(e.target.dataset.rel);
  if (modal) {
    document.querySelectorAll(".modal").forEach(el => {
      if (el == modal) {

        el.classList.toggle("show-modal");
      } else {
        el.classList.remove("show-modal");
      }
    });
  }
}

function windowOnClick(event) {
  if (event.target === modal) {
    toggleModal(event);
  }
}


wedding_POPUP.addEventListener("click", toggleModal);
closeButton.addEventListener("click", closeModal);
window.addEventListener("click", windowOnClick);
```

```css
/* Popup screen for each modal when pressed 
   buttons when pressed background changes
   setup for when clicked*/

.modal {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: scale(1.1);
  transition: visibility 0s linear 0.25s, opacity 0.25s 0s, transform 0.25s;
}


/*center of page  with padding and borders*/

.modal-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 359px;
  left: 624px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: white;
  padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
  width: 34%;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  height: 122%;
}


/*close button layout with hover background*/

.close-button {
  float: right;
  width: 1.5rem;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.close-button:hover {
  background-color: darkgray;
}


/*style of modal when its open */

.show-modal {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scale(1.0);
  transition: visibility 0s linear 0s, opacity 0.25s 0s, transform 0.25s;
}
```

```html
<div id="occasion">
  <button id="occassion_layout" class="wedding_POPUP" data-rel="wedding_modal">Wedding</button>
  <button id="occassion_layout" class="Birthday_POPUP" data-rel="birthday_modal">Birthday</button>
  <button id="occassion_layout" class="Party_POPUP" data-rel="holiday_modal">Holiday</button>
</div>


<div id="Wed_fill">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>

  <!--when the wedding button is pusehed what it will show show div boderline-->
  <div id="wedding_modal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <span class="close-button">&times;</span>

      <p>Wedding button clicked</p>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>

<div id="birthday_modal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close-button">&times;</span>

    <!--form for birthday-->
    <div class="Birth_fill">
      <div class="Birthday_form">
        <p>HAPPY BIRTHDAY button clicked</p>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>

<div id="party_modal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close-button">&times;</span>

    <!--form for birthday-->
    <div class="party_filled">
      <div class="party_form">
        <p>Party button clicked</p>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

This code isn't fully working, but I have to leave now.

Comment: question how come when you called the functions [[[[( ("click", toggleModal), ("click", closeModal); ("click", windowOnClick)]]]]] with a parameter but at the end of the program you called it without any parameters sent?

Comment: When the function is called by `addEventListener()`, the event is passed automatically.

Comment: Yeah this is all a bit new to me just gonna do little more research on these commands, thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0):

I took liberty to format a bit using flex.
I suggest a "toggle" for display using data attribute so you only have to "change" it not add/remove it - and you can use that in the CSS (I used "show" and "hide" values.
To open a modal, I used a "target" data as a class and selected by that - it could be a number of values/combinations.

I set up a "close" event for the X and then triggered them all to close when a button was clicked so if one is already open we only have one at a time open.

I did away with all the "position" css and used flex instead of `px` this way and that etc. which is hard to maintain from my experience.

Something you can build upon I think.

```js
const modals = document.querySelectorAll(".modal");
const actionButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".modal-activator");
const closeButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".close-button");

/* not used but could trigger the closeEvent etc. */
function windowOnClick(event) {
  if (event.target === modal) {
    toggleModal();
  }
}
// create close event 
const closeEvent = new Event('close-modal');
// Listen for the event.
closeButtons.forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener('close-modal', function(event) {
  let myModal = event.target.closest(".modal");
  myModal.dataset.showToggle = "hide";
}, false));

actionButtons.forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener('click', event => {
  // console.log(event.target.getAttribute("data-target-modal"));
  const dataAttrMap = event.target.dataset;
  const modalSelector = ".modal." + dataAttrMap.targetModal;
  // console.log(modalSelector);
  closeAllModals(closeButtons);
  const modalTarget = document.querySelector(modalSelector);
  modalTarget.dataset.showToggle = "show";
}));
closeButtons.forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  let myModal = event.target.closest(".modal");
  myModal.dataset.showToggle = "hide";
}, false));

function closeAllModals(buttons) {
  buttons.forEach(btn => btn.dispatchEvent(closeEvent));
}
```

```css
.contaner {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: start;
}

.occasion.contaner {
  flex-direction: row;
  column-gap: 0.5em;
  align-self: flex-start;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.modal {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  opacity: 0;
}

.modal-content {
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  margin-left: 0.5rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.close-button {
  align-self: flex-start;
  margin-left: auto;
  width: 1.5rem;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.close-button:hover {
  background-color: darkgray;
}


/* not used
.show-modal {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scale(1.0);
  transition: visibility 0s linear 0s, opacity 0.25s 0s, transform 0.25s;
}
*/

.modal[data-show-toggle="show"] {
  opacity: 1;
  display: flex;
  transform: scale(1.0);
  transition: visibility 0s linear 0s, opacity 0.25s 0s, transform 0.25s;
}

.modal[data-show-toggle="hide"] {
  display: none;
}
[data-target-modal]{padding: 0.5rem;border-radius: 0.5rem;}
[data-target-modal="wedding"]{background-color:pink;border-color:#ff8888;}
[data-target-modal="holiday"]{background-color:#AAAAFF;}
```

```html
<div class="page container">
  <div id="occasion" class="occasion contaner">
    <button class="wedding_POPUP modal-activator" data-target-modal="wedding" type="button">Wedding</button>
    <button class="Birthday_POPUP modal-activator" data-target-modal="birthday" type="button">Birthday</button>
    <button class="Party_POPUP modal-activator" data-target-modal="holiday" type="button">Holiday</button>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="modal wedding" data-show-toggle="hide">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <p>Wedding button clicked</p>
      </div>
      <span class="close-button">&times;</span>
    </div>
    <div class="modal birthday" data-show-toggle="hide">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="Birth_fill">
          <div class="Birthday_form">
            <p>HAPPY BIRTHDAY button clicked</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <span class="close-button">&times;</span>
    </div>
    <div class="modal holiday" data-show-toggle="hide">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="party_filled">
          <div class="party_form">
            <p>Party button clicked</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <span class="close-button">&times;</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for that, What do the brackets mean in the CSS with the show and hide commands if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: that is an attribute and the values for that - which is a data attribute (see the markup) and can be manipulated using the dataset re: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset  and also can be targeted with CSS as illustrated

Comment: I will also add some CSS for the buttons just to illustrate a CSS only example